# Is it possible to make an UIAlertView with 3 textfields?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uialertview

I need to input first, middle and last names when user will add a contact to his addressbook.

P.S.:
**Finally I found control**, which allows that: https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog

Comment: why does it have to be an AlertView? a custom view presented as popOver might be the better choice.

Comment: @vikingosegundo popover is only an option if it is on iPad

Comment: Sorry, I meant modal view.

Comment: There are popovers on github for iPhone also, btw.
I want UIAlertView because it's less code(I don't need to create one more controller) and less space on a screen.

Comment: if you want less code you should search for uialertview replacements which are using blocks instead of delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you suggest something I can use instead?

I'd present a modal view via [`presentViewController:animated:completion:` (ios 5+)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW75) or [`presentModalViewController:animated:` ios <5 (deprecated)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW29)

If you want to stick with an alertview, you can find replacements on [cocoacontrols.com](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tweetbot-like-uialertview-and-uiactionsheet-replacement).

---

[From the docs:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2)

> **Subclassing Notes**
>   The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this
>   class is private and must not be modified.

adding text views is modifying the view hierarchy and could lead to appstore submission refusal.

---

using [this category](http://www.glimsoft.com/01/07/how-to-inspect-subviews-hierarchy-of-any-uiview/) you can easily inspect the view hierarchy of any view. (or use `po [alertView recursiveDescription]` on the debugger console)

**Note: this is code that should NEVER be used in a real world application.**

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"
                                                        message:@"msg"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];

    UITextField *textFiled = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    [textFiled setText:@"dont try that at home"];
    [alertView addSubview:textFiled];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView printSubviewsWithIndentation:4];
```

we will log this hierarchy

```
[0]: class: 'UIImageView'
[1]: class: 'UILabel'
[2]: class: 'UILabel'
[3]: class: 'UIAlertButton'
   [0]: class: 'UIImageView'
   [1]: class: 'UIButtonLabel'
[4]: class: 'UITextField'
```

resulting in this

[image: screenshot of alertview mess]

The textView is just placed over all others. actually it must be placed under `[2]: class: 'UILabel'`. We could do this via fiddling with the view hierarchy (loop through it and re-arrange this) or by sublassing UIAlertView and overwriting `layoutSubviews`. Both things, apple does not want.

So to summarize it, if it comes to UIAlertView, you have 3 options:

1. live with it, as it is (remember, some forms of input are available via the predefined styles)
2. use some other view controller to present a modal view
3. use a replacement. but one that does not subclass UIAlertView.

---

---

**But if someone is still convinced that messing around with the view hierarchy *IS* a good idea and knows better than me and apple's engineers**, here is the code

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"
                                                    message:@"Please read carefully the next 3 lines"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alertView show];


CGFloat height = 25.0;

UILabel *msgLabel = [[alertView subviews] objectAtIndex:2];

UITextField *textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(msgLabel.frame.origin.x, msgLabel.frame.origin.y+msgLabel.frame.size.height, msgLabel.frame.size.width, height)];
[textField1 setText:@"dont try that at home"];
[textField1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
UITextField *textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(textField1.frame, 0, height + 4)];
[textField2 setText:@"REALLY! dont try that at home"];
[textField2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

UITextField *textField3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(textField2.frame, 0, height + 4)];
[textField3 setText:@"REALLY! dont try that at home"];
[textField3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

NSArray *followringSubviews = [[alertView subviews] subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [[alertView subviews] count] - 3)];
[followringSubviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    view.frame = CGRectOffset(view.frame, 0, 3*height);

}];
[alertView addSubview:textField1];
[alertView addSubview:textField2];
[alertView addSubview:textField3];

alertView.frame = CGRectUnion(alertView.frame, CGRectOffset(alertView.frame, 0, 80));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'll do it. But currently I can't understand why UIAlertView frame isn't changing, even if I do [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 90, 260, 50)];

Comment: as I said before: Apple does not want you to change the appearance. Maybe you can go around it by subclassing UIAlertView and overwrite `layoutSubviews`

Comment: You must set the new frame after calling `show`. see my *Dont try that at home* example.

Comment: @vikingosegundo the layout subviews does not seem to be invoked on iOS7 for a UIAlertView :(

Comment: @yonel, did you read the answer: **Note: this is code that should NEVER be used in a real world application.** and yes: in iOS 7 it is finally impossible, as it was always forbidden by documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You want you can do this way.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"msg" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
txtField.text=@"anoop here";
[alertView addSubview:txtField];
[alertView show];
```

EDIT:

Even a custom view will do your work. (as you can see in my previous edits.)

Create a custom view with custom shape size, color, text size etc, and then show it as a model window.

EDIT 2:

The above code wont run for iOS7.

Comment: Well, I see empty UIAlertView in this case

Comment: did you added anything in txtField?

Comment: The result is the same for empty/full textfields

Comment: Apple does not want user to change the appearance of UIAlertView except for the given styles introduced in iOS5.

Comment: @vikingosegundo : Yes thats why I gave that answer and then I edited the answer by adding another textfield. So I am still confused, which answer should i Post ??

Comment: Can you suggest something I can use instead?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I disagree. In iOS4 it was no textfield at all in alertview. Apple can't calculate all the cases.

Comment: See my edit:, create a custom view with custom shape size, color, text size etc, and then show it as a model window.

Comment: @Flink — what are you disagreeing on?

Comment: @Flink : i checked by addng text in custom txt and its working... i had to use teamviewer :)

Comment: I don't think that Apple don't want me to change appearance.
Also, I remember that I've seen UIAlerView with tableView inside it in cocoacontrols. I'll try and look how it was done

Comment: Yes... it is ios6.0, i am running XCode4.5

Comment: @Flink — of course you CAN change it, by messing around with the subviews. but those solutions are hacks that can break at any time that apple changes a hidden implementation detail.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya So strange. Can you please paste code to your answer?

Comment: and that apple doesnt want you to cange it, is well documented. (some wwdc video, where iOS 5 was introduced)

Comment: @Flik — you should have a closer look at https://github.com/MatthewLabs/MLTableAlert, it is a replacement. not even a subclass.

Comment: http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5409446/screenshot1-png-492k?da=y the screen shot or xcode and simulator.

Comment: from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html *Subclassing Notes
The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.*

Comment: @Flink — use a replacement. Annop's answer is modifying the view hierarchy and could lead to Appstore refusal.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya — the screenshot shows no textfield, neither the text "anoop".

Comment: @vikingosegundo Here is the right screenshot http://d.pr/i/wG1C. It shows textfield. But it's only one, so there is no meaning.

Comment: @vikingosegundo It's tf actually. But if you add second tf, then you can see http://d.pr/i/zgS1

Comment: why do u thing it is a textfield? the strings are passed in view the `init…` and probably added as labels in `layoutSubview` or some other hidden method. did you pars the alertviews subviews?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I can write in it. It's a textfield.
However I found control, thanks all.

Comment: @Flink — we are both right. I will show you in a second in my answer.

Comment: FYI: using `addSubView:` will be impossible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7

Comment: @vikingosegundo: Thanks for the info. :)   As I am not into iOS development, My profile is only OSX, so I was unaware about the changes in ios7.

Answer (score 0):

Use accessoryView property for alert view

```
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"change Password " message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
     CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 300);
     UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    UITextField* text1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10,self.view.frame.size.width-125, 30)];
    text1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    UITextField* text2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 45, self.view.frame.size.width-125, 30)];
    text2.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    UITextField* text3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 80, self.view.frame.size.width-125, 30)];
    text3.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    text1.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    text1.layer.borderWidth=1;
    text2.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    text2.layer.borderWidth=1;
    text3.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    text3.layer.borderWidth=1;
    text1.placeholder=@"  Enter  old password ";
   [view addSubview:text1];
   [view addSubview:text2];
   [view addSubview:text3];
    [alertView setValue:view forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [alertView show];
```